# DocuSign CLM integration with API

Tags: api, storage, docusignapi, envelope

I'm trying to figure out how to develop an integration for my company's application which needs to send contracts to recipients and download the signed documents to store them in the internal database. This part is clear (creating envelope, etc), but there is a requirement also to store the signed documents to the DocuSign CLM for those customers who use it actively. I have searched around but I cannot find lots of information about this.

Would there be a way to store the documents to the CLM? Or this is done automatically using the customer's DocuSign account which includes access to the CLM too?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For access to the DocuSign CLM APIs, please contact your DocuSign Account Manager. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. At this stage, I would like just to understand if this requirement can be fulfilled or not. I'm designing an integration that will be standard for all our customers, but some of them asked which are the capabilities to interact with DocuSign CLM, and I cannot find many references on the web. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, no one can help me? Thanks! :D

Comment: anybody else? Thanks!